# How to display audio at the right side of matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, librosa

The following code display the `image` and `audio` in the `top-bottom` style:

[image]

Here is the test code:

```
import librosa
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import IPython.display as ipd

def plot_it(name, audio, sample_rate):
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 1))
    plt.plot(audio)
    plt.gca().set_title(name)

    plt.show()

    ipd.display(ipd.Audio(data=audio, rate=sample_rate))
```

Is it possible for changing the "`top-bottom`" style to "`left-right`" style for displaying the `audio` at the right side of the `plt` figure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`GridspecLayout`](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Layout%20Templates.html#Grid-layout) which is similar to matplotlib's `GridSpec`. In order to direct to output into the needed grid cells, you can capture it using the [`Output`](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Output%20Widget.html) widget:

```
import librosa
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import IPython.display as ipd
from ipywidgets import Output, GridspecLayout

def plot_it(name, audio, sample_rate):
    grid = GridspecLayout(1, 2, align_items='center')
    out = Output()
    with out:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 1))
        ax.plot(audio)
        ax.set_title(name)
        plt.close(fig)
        ipd.display(ax.figure)
    grid[0, 0] = out
    out = Output()
    with out:
        ipd.display(ipd.Audio(data=audio, rate=sample_rate))
    grid[0, 1] = out
    ipd.display(grid)

name = 'nutcracker'
filename = librosa.example(name)
y, sr = librosa.load(filename)

plot_it(name, y, sr)
```

[image]

(It is essential to close the `figure`, otherwise you'll have double output of the figure. This is easier to do this using the OOP than the pyplot interface, that's why I changed your matplotlib code a bit)